# I get friends and all other users when trying to load only friends of the current user

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository, entity, dql

I am trying to load friends of a specific user after asking why I get null values of the friend of the user data it was responded that it was because of the lazy loading. So I was advised to add JOIN and I admit this was a miss from my side. But after adding the JOIN I get the data of the friend in the result and then I receive all the users from my users table for which I have not asked.

I have already tried removing the myuser from the SELECT, but this way I get the lazy loading problem again. I have tried LEFT JOIN (I admit it was dumb try from my side). But how can I correct this when there is no ON in the Doctrine Query Language.

My Entity(Friends):

```
class Friends
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="myfriends")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */

private $friendsWithMe;


/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="friendof")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */

private $afriendof;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="smallint")
 */
private $status;



/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getFriendsWithMe()
{
    return $this->friendsWithMe;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $friendsWithMe
 */
public function setFriendsWithMe($friendsWithMe)
{
    $this->friendsWithMe = $friendsWithMe;
}

/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getAfriendof()
{
    return $this->afriendof;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $afriendof
 */
public function setAfriendof($afriendof)
{
    $this->afriendof = $afriendof;
}

/**
 * @return integer
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * @param integer $status
 */
public function setStatus($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;
}
}
```

My Entity(User):

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->userPosts = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->myfriends = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->friendof = new ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * @var
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Friends", mappedBy="afriendof")
 */

private $friendof;
/**
 * @var
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Friends", mappedBy="friendsWithMe")
 */
private $myfriends;
```

My Repository(FriendsRepository):

```
public function personalFriends($userId){

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $result = $em->createQuery('SELECT friends, myuser FROM AppBundle\Entity\Friends friends 
    INNER JOIN AppBundle\Entity\User myuser WHERE friends.friendsWithMe = :userId AND friends.status = 1');
    $result->setParameter('userId', $userId);
    return $result->getResult();
}
```

The place where I call the repository:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $userId = $user->getId();
    $friends = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Friends::class)->personalFriends($userId);
    dump($friends);
    exit();
```

Results that I get now:
https://pastebin.com/2M4SYTLb
Results that I expect:
https://pastebin.com/BxsC9QbE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understand your problem. 
But from what I see you are asking for the data of the friends AND the data of the users when you are doing `'SELECT friends, myuser`.

Try only selecting `friends`

Like this:

`SELECT friend FROM AppBundle\Entity\Friends friend INNER JOIN AppBundle\Entity\User user WHERE friend.friendsWithMe = :userId AND friend.status = 1`

Then you'll only have as a result an array of Friends.

If there is still a problem you can add fetch="EAGER" so it wont be "LAZY"

`* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="myfriends", fetch="EAGER")`